# Using AOP to intercept Spring social control

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-social

My goal is intercept **ConnectionStatus** method in ConnectController class which is part of **Spring Social Web**:

The full method implantation :

```
/**
 * Render the status of the connections to the service provider to the user as HTML in their web browser.
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/{providerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String connectionStatus(@PathVariable String providerId, NativeWebRequest request, Model model) {
    setNoCache(request);
    processFlash(request, model);
    List<Connection<?>> connections = connectionRepository.findConnections(providerId);
    setNoCache(request);
    if (connections.isEmpty()) {
        return connectView(providerId); 
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("connections", connections);
        return connectedView(providerId);           
    }
}
```

I have the following aspect class to point cut the the above method:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;

@Aspect
public class SocialConnectionAspect {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConnectionAspect.class);

    @Around("execution(* org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connectionStatus(..))")
    public void processSocialConnesction(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        log.debug(pjp.getSignature().toLongString());
        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
        for (Object arg : args) {
            log.debug(arg.getClass().getSimpleName());
            boolean b = arg instanceof String;
            log.debug("is String: " + b);
            b = arg instanceof Model;
            log.debug("is Model: " + b);
            b = arg instanceof NativeWebRequest;
            log.debug("is NativeWebRequest: " + b);
        }
        pjp.proceed(args);
    }

}
```

However, every time I try to make social connection, the page throw the following exception:

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The mapped controller method class 'org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController' is not an instance of the actual controller bean instance 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89'. If the controller requires proxying (e.g. due to @Transactional), please use class-based proxying.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The mapped controller method class 'org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController' is not an instance of the actual controller bean instance 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89'. If the controller requires proxying (e.g. due to @Transactional), please use class-based proxying.
    HandlerMethod details: 
    Controller [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89]
    Method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)]
    Resolved arguments: 
    [0] [type=java.lang.String] [value=twitter]
    [1] [type=org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest] [value=ServletWebRequest: uri=/myproject/connect/twitter;client=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;session=85AF73CB172D0682D4FDA52E66DFE149;user=test.username1]

        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

- I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in here. Is it even possible to pointcut this spring controller?

Comment: The solution is in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-proxying)... and is hinted in the exception message, but it's not very clear.

Comment: @Augusto I add <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> as mentioned in the doc but I'm getting the following exception: 
**
Exception: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given**

Comment: Does the controller have a no arg constructor?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable Spring to use CGLIB to proxy your the classes in which you use your aspect:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

With the default settings, Spring only uses Java proxies. If your class doesn't implement any Interface (in your case `ConnectController`), the Java proxies will not work, and, therefore, a CGLIB proxy is needed.

But in your case, `ConnectController` doesn't have a default constructor, so CGLIB will fail as well. Which version of Spring are you using? From 4.0 you can use Objenesis to instantiate such classes. Have a look at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10594

Comment: I add <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> as mentioned in the doc but I'm getting the following exception:

 ** Exception: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given**